# How to trigger my own script function when a spreadsheet column's value was changed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm a new google app script developer, there's a problem that i can't solved.

I built some scripts and tried to use them in my spreadsheet, but they doesn't worked. What i want is to call my function when the target column value changed, then i wish the function will run a for-loop to set results into D2~D100 columns.

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us what you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events.

You should use onEdit() event and check if the range being edited meets your criteria. I did similar thing in my script. Hopefully this will help you.